# Dynamically change GSP template in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I'd like to refresh a template according to a value selected in a select component.

Typically, I have 3 templates that I want to load in my view :

- _templateA.gsp
- _templateB.gsp
- _templateC.gsp

In my GSP view, I have a select component with 3 choices:

- A
- B
- C

How can I dynamically change the template loaded in the code :

```
<g:render template="*myTemplate*"/>
```

On the onChange event of the select component? (if I select "A", templateA is loaded, then if I select "B", templateA is removed and templateB is loaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below we're POSTing the form contents using serialize to the `/myController/myAction` action.

Then based on the selected option we render the appropriate template and update the `myDiv` div in the view.

gsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '#mySelect' ).on( 'change' , function (event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/myController/myAction",
                type: "POST",
                data: $( '#myForm' ).serialize(),
                success: function ( data ) {
                    $( '#myDiv' ).html( data );
                },
                error: function( j, status, eThrown ) { console.log( 'Error ' + eThrown ) }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<g:form name="myForm">
    <g:select name="mySelect" from="${['A', 'B', 'C']}" />
</g:form>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
def myAction() {
    render template: "template${params.mySelect}"
}
```